# How to cretae instance of Interface conform to protocol as of type id<..>

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am leaning objective-c, and I am trying to learn the @protocol. I developed the below example. But what is not clear to me is
The code in main_1 and main_2. For  main_1, I thought it might be more or less like java for example, *sampleClass is instance of SampleClass, hence, it should not have access to ProcessComplete method. However, in Objective-c, the code works….

For main_2, I am trying to instantiate object of SampleClass that contains  SampleClass  as implementor of the protocol. Unlike the code in main_1, I supposed or thought that in the code in main_1 is provide instance of SampleClass but NOT as implementor of the protocol.

1-Please correct me if I am not right.
2-please let me know why in code main_2, I received the following errors:

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to '__strong id<PrintClientProtocol> *' is disallowed with ARC
Pointer to non-const type 'id<PrintClientProtocol>' with no explicit ownership
Incompatible pointer types initializing '__strong id<PrintClientProtocol> *' with an expression of type 'SampleClass *'
```

**main_1**

```
    SampleClass *sampleClass = [[SampleClass alloc] init];
    [sampleClass startAction];
    [sampleClass processCompleted];
```

**main_2**

```
    id<PrintClientProtocol> *sampleClass2 = [[SampleClass alloc] init];
    [sampleClass2 startAction];
    [sampleClass2 processCompleted];
```

**printClass.h**

```
#ifndef PrintClass_h
#define PrintClass_h
#endif /* PrintClass_h */

//The class/interface that to execute the protocols in the client contract. execution is to be done according
//to the DELEGATE Class/Interface
@interface PrintClass :NSObject {
   id implementor;//instance of the DELEGATE/implementor and executor class/interface
    //change id to SampleClass for testing
}

- (void) printDetails;
- (void) setDelegate: (id) implementor;

@end
```

**printClass.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PrintClass.h"
#import "SampleClass.h"

@implementation PrintClass

- (void) printDetails {
    NSLog(@"Printing Details");
    [implementor processCompleted];
}

- (void) setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {
    implementor = newDelegate;
}

@end
```

**SampleClass.h**

```
#ifndef SampleClass_h
#define SampleClass_h


#endif /* SampleClass_h */
#import "PrintClientProtocol.h"
//the class/interface that provide implementions and execution of it, which is the "DELEGATE"
@interface SampleClass : NSObject<PrintClientProtocol>
- (void)startAction;
@end
```

**SampleClass.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SampleClass.h"
#import "PrintClass.h"

@implementation SampleClass

-(void)startAction {
    PrintClass *printClass = [[PrintClass alloc] init];
    [printClass setDelegate: self];
    [printClass printDetails];
}

-(void) processCompleted {
    NSLog(@"PROCESS_COMPLETED.....");
}

@end
```

**PrintClientProtocol**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

//the protocol that demands or needs implementor and executor "Client/Delegatee Protocol"
@protocol PrintClientProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) processCompleted;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the class `SampleClass` says that it conforms to the protocol `PrintClientProtocol`. That means it automatically inherits all the members declared in the protocol `PrintClientProtocol`, including `-processCompleted`. This is the same as what you would expect in Java.

In `main_2`, the problem is that the type `id<PrintClientProtocol>` is already a pointer-to-object type, akin to `SampleClass *`. By writing `id<PrintClientProtocol> *`, you are writing a pointer-to-pointer-to-object type, which is not compatible with the right side, which has a pointer-to-object type.